Is shading materials in ray tracing/path tracing associative and/or commutative?
I have been fiddling around a ray tracer in the tutorial Ray Tracing: The Next Week. And I noticed that the author simply multiplies attenuation of materials hit in each intersection:
ray scattered;
color attenuation;
color color_from_emission = rec.mat->emitted(rec.u, rec.v, rec.p);

if (!rec.mat->scatter(r, rec, attenuation, scattered))
    return color_from_emission;

color color_from_scatter = attenuation * ray_color(scattered, depth-1, world);

return color_from_emission + color_from_scatter;

Here, even though color_from_emission + color_from_scatter is returned as the shading result, the only material with a non-trivial emitted() method is diffuse_light, which can be absorbed into scatter() without much trouble.
What I am trying to say is, the tutorial have left me an impression that when shading samples, you can store the material pointer, uv coords and perhaps the hit angle into a buffer similar to the G-buffer in rasterization without performing the actual shading part right away. And after all rays have finished their intersections, you compute the color of samples by processing that buffer, with techniques enabled by associative and/or commutative properties of materials. Do materials used by real-world ray tracers have these two properties?
Directly searching with keywords like "ray tracing material commutative" leads me nowhere, and I can imagine that nonlinear materials do not have associative nor commutative properties. But I don't know whether those materials are commonplace.
